# MySQL Group_Concat Distinct By Id

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, group-concat

Is it possible to `group_concat` records by distinct Ids:

`GROUP_CONCAT(Column2 BY DISTINCT Column1)`

I need to get the values from `column2` by distinct values from `column1`. Because there are repeating values in column 2, that's why I can't use distinct on `column2`.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Sample Table Records:

```
ID  Value
1   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
4   C
```

Using the `GROUP_CONCAT` the I wanted [`GROUP_CONCAT(Value BY DISTINCT Id)`], I will have an output:

`A, B, B, C`

**EDIT 2**

Somehow got my `group_concat` working:

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(Id, '|', Value))`

This will display the concatenated values by distinct id, just need to get rid of the Id somewhere. You can do it without the `concat` function, but I need the separator. This may not be a good answer but I'll post it anyway.

Comment: can you sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one, (*the simpliest way*)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, VALUE
    FROM TableName
) a
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c058/3)

Comment: Thanks John! So there is no functionality for `GROUP_CONCAT` on my question? I have a very long query, I can't use distinct inside the subquery.

Comment: @KaeL not sure to answer your question but i really think that you need to create a separate query to get distinct rows den join it with your current.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I'll try to use a separate query, I'm worrying a little with the performance, got very large tables involved.

Comment: if you have proper index on your tables then you don't have to worry much. don't worry if you have subqueries. *"it has to be done to achieve your results."*

Comment: Thanks for the info John, my tables are well indexed. I just added some tweaks to make my `group_concat` work. I'll add my answer in my question so I can accept your answer, since it helped me think a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP_CONCAT` function support `DISTINCT` expression.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value) FROM table_name GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I'll check this one @xdazz, will get back on a moment. Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty much the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM (SELECT id, value FROM table GROUP BY id, value) AS d
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin, but I'm thinking if there is a way to use distinct on another column inside the group_concat. Got a very long query, and had no where to go. Using your answer will have a lot of changes. :)